# I been confused by this nested summation

Tags: summation

My answer:

> $$\begin{align*}
> \sum_{x=1}^{y-1}\sum_{y=6}^8x+y&=\sum_{x=1}^{6-1}x+6+\sum_{x=1}^7x+7+\sum_{x=1}^8x+8\\
> &=45+63+84\\
> &=192
> \end{align*}$$

(Original [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HFNz.jpg).)

This nested summation is tricky.
Can someone explain to me why the above answer is wrong?
WolframAlpha shows a different answer:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(sum+(x%2By)+y%3D6+to+8)+x%3D1+to+y-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you really need more parentheses:

$$\sum_{x=1}^{y-1}\sum_{y=6}^8(x+y)$$

and

$$\sum_{x=1}^{6-1}(x+6)+\sum_{x=1}^7(x+7)+\sum_{x=1}^8(x+8)\;.$$

The real problem is that the original double sum is notational nonsense. The $y$ in the outer sum is a constant and should not be used as the name of the index of summation in the inner sum: these two $y$s **have to** represent different things and should not have the same name. We could try to fix the problem by changing the name of the index for the inner summation from $y$ to $k$, say, but then we can’t tell whether it’s supposed to be

$$\sum_{x=1}^{y-1}\sum_{k=6}^8(x+y)\;,$$

with the $y$ of the general term understood to be the constant appearing in the upper limit of the outer sum, or

$$\sum_{x=1}^{y-1}\sum_{k=6}^8(x+k)\;,$$

with the $y$ of the general term understood to be the inner index of summation. Wolfram|Alpha adopted the second interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

With a notation that makes sense,

$$\sum_{y=6}^8\sum_{x=1}^{y-1}(x+y)=\\
(1+6+2+6+3+6+4+6+5+6)+\\
(1+7+2+7+3+7+4+7+5+7+6+7)+\\
(1+8+2+8+3+8+4+8+5+8+6+8+7+8)=\\
(15+5\cdot6)+(21+6\cdot7)+(28+7\cdot8)=\\
192.$$

---

Wolfram indeed evaluated

$$\sum_{x=1}^{y-1}\sum_{z=6}^8(x+z)=\sum_{x=1}^{y-1}(x+6+x+7+x+8)=\sum_{x=1}^{y-1}(3x+21)=\frac32(y-1)y+21(y-1)$$ which is a function of $y$.

---

An even weirder interpretation is

$$\sum_{x=1}^{y-1}\sum_{z=6}^8(x+y)=\sum_{x=1}^{y-1}(x+y+x+y+x+y)=\sum_{x=1}^{y-1}(3x+3y)=\frac32(y-1)y+3y(y-1).$$

Comment: how did $z$ arise?

Comment: @hypergeometric: introduced to disambiguate

Comment: does it not then change the original summation?